# "what do you say you we meet up for a cup of coffee" or "what do you say if we meet up for cup of coffee"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Tell me please which sentence sounds grammatically correct.

> What do you say we meet up for a cup of coffee sometime.
>
> What do you say **if** we meet up for a cup of coffee sometime.

What I am trying to say is I am asking if the person would like to meet up for a cup of coffee.

Comment: There's also: What would you say to [etc.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sentence is idiomatic:

> ✔ What do you say we meet up for a cup of coffee sometime?

The second sentence is not. In order to add *if*, the verb tenses also need to be changed:

> ✘ What **do** you say ***if*** we **meet** up for a cup of coffee sometime?
>   ✔ What **would** you say ***if*** we **met** up for a cup of coffee sometime?

Answer (score 1):

"What do you say we X?" is just one of many idiomatic ways of saying "Do you want to X?" (as in, do X together). Literally, I guess it means, "what do you say in response to the suggestion that we X?"

You could also tag it on the end of a suggestion like so: "I'd like to meet for a cup of coffee later. What do you say?"

I wouldn't analyze it further than that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of idiomatic ways of saying this, for example:

> Let's meet up for a cup of coffee sometime
>   Would you fancy a cup of coffee at a time that suits you?
>   How about a cup of coffee once you're finished work?
>   I'd love a chat over a cup of coffee at your leisure
>   May I invite you to a cup of coffee when you're free?

And so on....

Comment: Do my sentences sound right?